# how to get last 10 records form sql table in asc order

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
select top(10) from customer order by customer_id desc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * 
from (select top 10 * from customer order by customer_id desc) a
order by  customer_id
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "order by a.customer_id"?

Comment: I dont think it is necessarry.. it is just like doing 

select top 10 * from customer c order by customer_id desc

Answer (score 2):

This work fine in MS SQL but for MySQL we would have to go
SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: I am not sure but i think in mysql it will be

select * from (select  * from customer order by customer_id desc limit 10) a order by customer_id

or something similar.

Comment: Or you could go Select * From customer Where customer_id in (select customer_id order by customer_id desc) order by customer_id.  This way you don't transfer the whole database only for the customer_id.  This will depend how many records you will get back.  A few you don't mind, but if you have a large recordset and many record the economy of bandwidth will be noticed :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're missing the column list that you'd like retrieved from the table.

Consider:

```
select top(10) 
*
from customer order by customer_id desc
```

or

```
select top(10) 
customer_id, customer_name
from customer order by customer_id desc
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use:
    SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 10